# Web page real time updates with Javascript and Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, events, notifications, dom-events

What Javascript event can I use for handling real time updates on a web page with ajax?

For example; Mouse_move would create frequent ajax post requests. I need a timer event, like in each 5 seconds, update notifications, check if new notification available.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the setTimeout function and replace alertMsg() with your ajax function. See the tutorial here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

```
function timeMsg()
{
    var t=setTimeout("alertMsg()",5000);
}

function alertMsg()
{
alert("Hello");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need events at all. See `setTimeout` or `setInterval`.